# How to pack build file with upx via eclipse

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, build

I using Eclipse to compile c code.

How can I configure automatically that the build file will pack with upx?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Eclipse documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_settings_steps.htm), you have the ability to add a custom *Post-build step*:

[image]

Not tested, but you could use this example, and adjust it for your needs:

```
upx -o $(EXE_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME)-packed $(EXE_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME)
```

or

```
upx -o $(PROJECT_LOC)/$(PROJECTNAME)-packed $(PROJECT_LOC)/$(PROJECTNAME)
```

depending how you configured your project variables.